# CFDOCUMENT inserts some margin on left and right even if set to 0

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-11, cfdocument

I have this code running in Coldfusion 11.

```
<cfset fileName = "test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" reset="true">
<cfheader  name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fileName#">
<cfdocument localurl="yes" format="pdf" pagetype="letter" margintop=".5" marginbottom=".5" marginright="0" marginleft="0" orientation="portrait" unit="in" backgroundvisible="yes" overwrite="yes" fontembed="no">
    <cfdocumentsection>
        <div style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc; margin: 0 0 0 0;padding: 0 0 0 0;">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    </cfdocumentsection>
</cfdocument>
```

This produces a PDF like this:
[image]

The problem is that I have set the margin and padding of the div to 0 but still there is some space on the left and right.

Is there a way to remove this space programmatically so that the background spans the complete width of the page?

Update(7th August 2017)

I have updated the code as per comment/suggestion from James Moberg. But the issue still persists. Here is the updated code

```
<cfset fileName = "test.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" reset="true">
<cfheader  name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fileName#">
<cfdocument localurl="yes" format="pdf" pagetype="letter" margintop=".5" marginbottom=".5" marginright="0" marginleft="0" orientation="portrait" unit="in" backgroundvisible="yes" overwrite="yes" fontembed="no">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
        <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered)" />
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;padding: 0;">

    <cfdocumentsection>
        <div style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc; margin: 0;padding: 0;">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    </cfdocumentsection>

    </body>
    </html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: You don't have a BODY tag. If you view that with your browser, there will be padding/margin too. Add BODY with margin/padding of "0" and see if it makes any difference. (If you want better font/CSS/SVG/border support, check out WKHTMLTOPDF. I use it w/CF8-2016.)

Comment: Hello @JamesMoberg, thank you for the suggestions. I tried using the body tag but the issue still persists. I hope I have used it properly along with cfdocumentsection. I am editing some old code which is implemented using cfdocument. Maybe in the long run I can think about using WKHTMLTOPDF but right now I am in a hurry to implement some changes to the current functionality.

Comment: Are you using CSS in the body tag?  The CFDocument HTML parser is outdated.  You may need to use leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"

Comment: CFdocument CSS parser doesn't always "get" all the CSS you use. Try "margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;..." etc. Might also try it _without_ the <cfdocumentsection> tag which isn't doing a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have been able to create full custom pdf grids with coldfusion using css relative and absolute positions. Replace your cfdocumentsection with the following.

```
<cfdocumentsection>
  <div style="position:relative;left:-0.06in;width:102%;">
    <div style="background-color:#cccccc;">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:red;">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</cfdocumentsection>
```